# How to remove last element for a Singly Linked list in O(1)?

Tags: java, linked-list

Assume that I have a singly linked list with sentinel. To remove the last element in O(1) time, I need to maintain handle to last 2 elements. But maintaining handle to last two elements complicates the add operation.

Is there a way to remove the last element of a singly linked list with sentinel in O(1) without maintaining handle to last 2 elements? I would much appreciate any sample code in java.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're writing your own linked list (e.g. is this for a homework?) Normally, you should just use a new LinkedList<...>() which provides the same behavior as a doubly-linked-list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a singly linked list implemented in the normal way will be an `O(N)` operation.

Retaining a handle on the last element isn't that complicated, and singly-linked list implementations often do it so that you can add at the end in `O(1)`.  However, maintaining the link to the last element in the face of an `O(1)` "remove last" operation is not possible.

Think about it.  Suppose I have somewhere to keep pointers to the last and 2nd to last nodes.  When I remove the last node, I need to:

1. Update the `next` pointer in the 2nd to last node to be null,
2. Update the `last` pointer to point to the 2nd to last node.
3. Update the `secondToLast` pointer to point to the node before it.

But how do I do the last step without traversing the list from the start ... which is an `O(N)` operation?

Now I suppose you could code your linked list so that removing the last element is `O(1)` *the first time you do it*, and `O(N)` on subsequent times ... until you add a new element at the end.  But unless you've got an unusual use-case, this "optimization" won't be worth it.

---

You are probably better off using `java.util.LinkedList` which uses a doubly-linked list, and has a `removeLast()` method that is `O(1)`.`

Answer (score 4):

No, removing from the end is only applicable to doubly linked lists.
You need the back pointer to put the new NULL terminator on the previous link. I suggest making the list doubly linked to fulfil your requirements.

Are you making your own container? Why not use java.util.LinkedList, which is doubly linked?